# excel pair two columns from two tables using another column using vlookup

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have three table, table1 has Serial Number and ID, table2 has ID and Product Name, I need to fill table3 with Serial Number and matching Product Name using VLOOKUP
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0eGP.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do this with a nested Vlookup. 
One lookup to return the ID for the Serial Number, then use that ID in a second Vlookup to get the Product Name.

```
=VLOOKUP(VLOOKUP(H2,A2:B4,2,FALSE),D2:E4,2,FALSE)
```

You will need to populate the Serial Numbers in the 3rd table for this to work.
I created a copy of your tables so you can see what is going on.

[image: Vlookups]